# External Load Balancer for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: routes, load-balancing, kubernetes, haproxy

I want to implement a simple Layer 7 Load Balancer in my kubernetes cluster which will allow me to expose kubernetes services to external consumers.

I will create a simple ha-proxy based container which will observe kubernetes services and respective endpoints and reload its backend/frontend configuration (complemented with SYN eating rule during reload)

This will allow me to access kubernetes services like SVCa, SVCb, SVCc over

```
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCa -------> Pod endpoints.....
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCb -------> Pod endpoints..... 
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCc -------> Pod endpoints.....
```

How would above approach work compared to

(1) ha-proxy forwarding all the requests to clusterIP address of kubernetes services.

```
 http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCa ------->clusterIP-SVCa
 http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCb ------->clusterIP-SVCa
 http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCc ------->clusterIP-SVCa
```

(2) ha-proxy load-balancing requests to worker-node-ip:port obtained by creating NodePort type services

```
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCa  --------> node1:p1, node2:p1, node3:p1
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCb  --------> node1:p2, node2:p2, node3:p2
http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCc  --------> node1:p3, node2:p3, node3:p3
```

Note: My k8s cluster is running on custom solution (on-premise VMs)

Answer (score 3):

I think a nginx IngressController can work better in this case.
You only have to set the backend service and the hostname inside the ingress definition.

Take a look here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx

Comment: IngressController will be doing no different than itel (1) in my question.

http://load-balancer-ip:port/SVCa ---->SVCa.svc.cluster.local      . This will further get resolved to either clusterIP-SVCa or Pod Endpoints for services of type clusterIP and of type headless respectively

Comment: Also I am not considering NGINX IngressController for my production use case as it is Experimental at this stage

Comment: Why do you consider the NGINX IngressController as Experimental?

Comment: Well because Ingress as a feature is still evolving, but regardless of that even with Ingress/IngressController my challenge will still remain same. IngressController will take an external service call to SVCa.svc.cluster.local which will further get resolved to clusterIP address and it will further depend on DNS to provide primitive round-robin. In this whole scenario the power of  advanced load-balancer like haproxy/nginx is getting lost.

Comment: The nginx ingress controller do not uses dns or services, it goes directly to the endpoints to provide load balancing or sticky sessions. If you check the https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx#debug--troubleshooting it shows an example of an upstream using the IP of the pod

Comment: I just opened https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/1611 to improve the docs

Answer (score 0):

(2) This is not ideal if your cluster is very dynamic without predictable node names. This is also very very anti-pattern to immutable infrastructure- if that is something you are working towards.

(1) This will work, but relies on kube proxy for proxying to another node- which is not super intelligent right now, you are essentially going from haproxy (powerful proxy) to kube proxy (relatively dumb proxy) to pod- adding an extra jump and some (although minimal) latency

Your original plan is probably the best, and is essentially the same as an ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on having a dynamic cluster, indeed you will need to implement something via the operator model to automatically update the external LB with the destination IP addresses (of the ingress ports).

This is typically accomplished via Netris/Metallb/F5.